# An equation of tangential axis to a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a following mathematical problem:

> Let's consider a curve: $$\alpha \left(t \right)  =  \left(\frac{1}{4}t^4 , \frac{1}{3}t^3 , \frac{1}{2}t^2 \right)  , t \in R$$
>   Find an equation of tangential axis of the curve $\alpha$ which is
>   parallel to a plane $x + 3y + 2z = 0$.

Apparently, I don't know what 'tangential axis of a curve' means. During my previous exercises, I have encountered 'a normal axis of a curve' - a straight line described by a normal vector. In this case I just had to calculate $\alpha'' \left( t \right)$ and put it into an equation of a straight line $t\alpha'' \left( t_{0} \right)  + \alpha \left( t_{0} \right)$. However, in this case it doesn't seem to make any sense because if a calculate tangent $\alpha' \left( t_{0} \right)$ and insert it into an equation of a line then I don't see any way how I can make it parallel to a plane (because vector $\alpha' \left( t_{0} \right)$ already describes if it is parallel to a plane or not).

Is my intuition about a tangential axis to a curve correct?

Comment: Maybe (I'm french) "tangential axis" simply means "a line which is tangent to the curve", meaning it is directed by $\alpha'(t)$ when $\alpha'(t)\ne0"... There is nothing clear on Wikipedia.

Comment: First of all, $\alpha$ is not arclength-parametrized, so be careful (in general). They're just asking you when $\alpha'(t)$ is parallel to that plane. How do you tell when a vector is parallel to (i.e., contained in) a plane?

Comment: It is enough to take $\alpha’(t)$ and calculate dot product with a normal vector of the plane. Then check for which t it equals 0. I just wasn’t sure if this is the answer that author of this exercise had in mind.